# Как починить кодировку в логах make

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Изучаю фреймворк treefrog, это фреймворк для создания web приложений на плюсах. Он работает на базе QT. У treefrog есть свой автогенератор файлов через консольные команды, но я пытаюсь пока обойтись без него и собрать либы через qtcreator. Тот, в свою очередь, использует jom. И вот с ним есть некоторые проблемы, во первых он выдает какую-то несуразицу с поломанной кодировкой, вместо описания проблемы. Во-вторых хотелось бы понять на чем именно он ломается при сборке. Наверное у него должен быть какой-то свой собственный файл с логами и там наверняка должно быть больше подробностей про ошибку. Вот такой лог выдает мне QT:

> cd helpers\ && ( if not exist Makefile
> D:\Qt-MSVC\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile
> D:\practice\treefrog\blogapp\blogapp\helpers\helpers.pro -spec
> win32-msvc ) && D:\Qt-MSVC\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile
> D:\Qt-MSVC\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release  cd
> models\ && ( if not exist Makefile
> D:\Qt-MSVC\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile
> D:\practice\treefrog\blogapp\blogapp\models\models.pro -spec
> win32-msvc ) && D:\Qt-MSVC\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile
> D:\Qt-MSVC\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release  cd views
> && ( if not exist Makefile D:\Qt-MSVC\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe
> -o Makefile D:\practice\treefrog\blogapp\blogapp\views\views.pro -spec win32-msvc ) && D:\Qt-MSVC\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile     cd
> _src\ && ( if not exist Makefile D:\Qt-MSVC\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile
> D:\practice\treefrog\blogapp\blogapp\views_src_src.pro -spec
> win32-msvc ) && D:\Qt-MSVC\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile
> tmake -f ../../config/application.ini -v .. -d . -P "tmake" ­Ґ
> пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ© Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё
> Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬. jom:
> D:\practice\treefrog\blogapp\blogapp\views_src\Makefile [source.list]
> Error 1 jom: D:\practice\treefrog\blogapp\blogapp\views\Makefile
> [sub-_src-make_first] Error 2 jom:
> D:\practice\treefrog\blogapp\blogapp\Makefile
> [sub-views-make_first-ordered] Error 2 23:47:12: Процесс
> «D:\Qt-MSVC\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe» завершился с кодом 2. Ошибка
> при сборке/развёртывании проекта blogapp (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.15.2
> MSVC2019 64bit) Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тулчан нормально настройте, ибо та самая несуразица

> Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ© Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё
> Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.

в переводе на человеческий звучит как

> Не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или
> пакетным файлом.